# Unable to select elements from a table

Tags: sql, ssms

I stored columns from one table to another and i want to see what the second table contains.

for example:

```
select a.bc,
       a.cd,
       b.ef
into #table_1
from table_2 a
     inner join table_3 b
        on a.key = b.key
 
select ex.bc from #table_1 ex
```

This wouldn't print anything when I want to see elements in the ex.bc from table_1. I am new to sql and I am not understanding why it wouldn't show.

Comment: Hint:  `select * from #table_1`.

Comment: What does `select a.bc,
       a.cd,
       b.ef
from table_2 a
     inner join table_3 b
        on a.key = b.key` give you?  My guess is 0 rows.  Perhaps sample data would be helpful.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I tried that again today and I got an error saying "Invalid object name #table_1"

Comment: @Aiswarya . . . If you want the table to persist, then don't use the `#`.  That makes a temporary table.